# how to convert elements of void type to an integer array type?

Tags: c++, arrays, void

// convert elements of void x to an integer array

int elem(void* x,int size){

```
 int* temp = new temp[size];
 for(int i = 0;i < size ; i++){
     temp[i] = (int*)x[i]; //  <--- this is what i want
 // assign all element of x to temp
 }    
}

int main(){

        int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int num = elem(&a,10);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a `void *`? What does `elem` do?

Comment: elem return number of element of x

Comment: Use a template instead. Otherwise, make it an int*.

Comment: Precisely. A template works fine for getting the size of the array. A `void *` does not, as you'd have to pass in the size for it to know. Of course, you could also use `std::array` and just use `.size()`.

Comment: thats not my concern. i just need to convert all elements of x to a temp array and return the num of elements of temp.

Comment: Yeah, use an std::vector or std::array. They already have the size for you.

Comment: dude.i cannot change the parameter type because that's exactly what i've been asked. i just wanted to know how do i cast so that i can get all my elements that are stored to an address form in void x to a int temp array elements. i knw i need a sizeof().

Comment: How does knowing the type help you know the size of the array?

Comment: can you give me an example with all necessary things that i need in elem function so that i can convert x to int array?

Comment: @user2901571 you can *only* have a *single* parameter of type `void*` ? is that correct? You said " i just need to convert all elements of x". `x` *has no elements* in the context of this function. It is simply an address. And even if said-address is backed by an `int[]` or a `char[]` or whatever, there is no intrinsic *magnitude* unless *you* specify it (such as a `void*` that actually addresses a `struct { size_t N; int* ar; };` or some such protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In `main()` it should be `int num = elem(&a[0]);`, and in the function, put `int *int_ptr = (int *)x;` and then work with `int_ptr`.

The `elem` function has no way of knowing how many elements are in the array, so you will either have to pass this as a second parameter, or use something else instead of `void *`.

Alternatively you could put a sentinel value on the end of `a[]`, similar to how a string uses `'\0'` to indicate its end.

Comment: Yeah. There's no reasonable way  to get the array size after you initialise it, unless you keep track of it. Also, use reinterpret_cast, or static_cast.

Comment: perhaps even if i add a parameter of size than again how do i assign all elements to temp int array elements ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a new array inside the `elem` function and copy over all the elements from `a` ?

Comment: You want to copy all the elements to a new array?

Comment: Matt, that's not standard c++. Also, you should use std::copy.

Comment: sorry, thought we were in C for some reason